# Why -1 equals 4th byte of integer -5?

Tags: c++, binary

Why does this code deduce a **true** (or **1** without `std::boolalpha`)

```
   char* arr = new char[4];
   int* i = new (arr) int(-5);
   char c = -1;
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << (arr[3] == c) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Undefined behavior can do unexpected things.  Presumably, your platform is little endian, and presumably your platform an `int` if 4 bytes, and presumably your platform `char` is signed.  So `arr[3]` is `char(-1)` and c is `char(-1)`, so they match as equal.  If any of those presumptions don't hold (as they don't on my machine), strange things can happen.

Comment: @tg0w -5 internally is represented like 0xfffffffb. So extracting any byte except the byte with the value 0xfb you will get 0xff. It is the same representation of -1 in an object of the type char.

Comment: Why would you ever ask this question, when you could have hex dumped the array, or inspected it in the debugger, in the time it took to post? Or do you really want to know _why_ signed integers are represented in a particular way?

Comment: @Eljay Could be helpful if you told why you consider this "undefined behavior"

Comment: @eerorika Are you sure about that. AFAIK a char pointer is allowed as alias for any (parts of an) object of any type.

Comment: It's UB if `int` is less than 4 bytes (since `arr[3]` won't be initialized), or if `int` is more than 4 bytes (since `new char[4]` isn't big enough for a placement new), or if `new char[4]` doesn't meet the alignment requirements of `int`.

Comment: @Eljay Aren't dynamic allocations guaranteed to be aligned to the maximum natural alignment?

Comment: @Eljay Dynamic allocation will make sure you don't get into alignment problems. And further, reading uninitialized memory using a char-pointer is (afaik) not undefined behavior.

Comment: @eerorika • maybe, I'm not 100% sure.  We'd need a `language-lawyer` to chime in, and I hung up my language lawyer spurs when C++11 came out.

Comment: @4386427 Actually, yea. I was confused. Cleaned up misleading comments.

Comment: @eerorika true but that would only happen in case `sizeof(int) > 4`. I don't think anything here is undefined behavior. It's just about how `-5` is stored on a specific system

Comment: @4386427 Well, no UB except when `sizeof(int) > 4`.

Comment: @4386427 I've retracted my statement.  Looks like it'll be okay since you are allowed to alias through a char pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this code deduce a true

Depending on the system used to run the program, the output could be either true or false, or behaviour of the program could be undefined.

On systems where negative numbers are represented using two's complement (which is very common, and will be guaranteed since C++20) and where byte-endianness is little endian (which is somewhat common on desktop systems; not so much elsewhere) and where the size of `int` is exactly 4, it just so happens that the byte `arr[3]` has the value `-1`. An example of CPU architecture where all of these conditions match is x86 a non-matching example is AVR32.

On big endian systems, this would not be the case and output wouldn't be true. And on systems where the size of `int` is less than 4 bytes, the byte could be uninitialised in which case output could be either true or false. In case where size of `int` is greater than 4 bytes, the behaviour of the program would be undefined.

Comment: Re “the output could be either true or false, or behaviour of the program could be undefined”: Well, I am glad we have narrowed it down.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect `arr` in a debugger you will probably see that it has the value `0xfbffffff`. This will be true if your computer uses little-endian byte order, in which the least significant byte is stored at the lowest address. For your code to execute as you seem to expect, you should be examining `arr[0]`. Also, your code as written would probably execute as you expect on a machine that uses big-endian byte order.

Comment: The value will be 0xfbffffff regardless of endianness (but may be something else due to other factors).